# Robot Framework-Locator not found-Ebay website

Tags: python, xpath, robotframework

I am trying to make a small robot framework with e bay website but every time I get locator not found in my Click Element, I have tried everything even Sleep and Wait until Element is visible. My code is this one.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  Basic Search Functionality
Library  SeleniumLibrary
*** variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Verify basic search functionality
    [documentation]  This test case verifies the basic search functionality
    [tags]  Functional

    Open Browser  http://www.ebay.com  chrome
    Maximize Browser Window
    Input Text  //*[@id="gh-ac"]  mobile
    Press Keys  //*[@id="gh-btn"]  [Return]
    Page Should Contain  results for mobile
    Sleep  10s
    Wait Until Element Is Visible  xpath=//* 
    [@id="nid-pZ5-4"]/button/span
    Click Element  xpath=//*[@id="nid-pZ5- 
    4"]/button/span
    Close Browser
```

The element is in the picture.
[The element I am trying click it can be seen in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxZWx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `xpath`

```
xpath=//*[@id="nid-pZ5-4"]/button/span
```

does look correct. Since I could not locate any element in UI.

try this instead :

```
xpath = //span[text()='Condition']/ancestor::button
```

Comment: Omg you're amazing. It works. May I ask you what was the problem? How you knew that could work?

Comment: Sounds good ! the locator that you are using was not correct, `//*[@id="nid-pZ5- 
    4"]/button/span`, I think the id will change on every run due to backend react calls.

Comment: what you did to find the correct xpath so I can replicate in the future? I'm doing tests on e-bay so probably I'll encounter same problem in the future

Comment: ahh,  xpath is a skill, unfortunately there is no tool that can generate the relative xpath, you have to learn it how to write xpath. I would recommend this https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp